# ASP.NET VB json into MySql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

can someone help me to make this Code much more efficene?

```js
        Dim SqlString = "INSERT test (id, fname, lname) VALUES (?,?,?)"

        Dim json As String = File.ReadAllText("c:\test.json")
        Dim array As JArray = JArray.Parse(json)

        Using Con As New MySqlConnection("Database=*;Server=*;User Id=*;Password=*")
            Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(SqlString, Con)

                For Each item As JObject In array
                    Con.Open()
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", item("id"))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fname", item("fname"))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lname", item("lname"))
                    cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                    Con.Close()
                Next
            End Using

            Response.Write("Done!")

        End Using
```

Some Help would be great, i need to insert more then 100k entrys, every Day.

Comment: Please consider using http://codereview.stackexchange.com as your code is already working.

Comment: This may be OK for Code Review site if the code is already working, but consider adding more context to your question if you post there, as in its current form it is a bit vague.

Comment: Don't open and close the connection for each item.  Open it just after the first `Using` and close it just before "Done!" (or just let dispose close it).  You can also add the parameters to the command once outside of the loop and just change their values in the loop.